# Terminal does not show prompt until enter is pressed in Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: command-line, prompt

When I launch the terminal in Ubuntu 14.04.2, it does not show the prompt until the enter key is pressed. I think some process is preventing the prompt from appearing. Could anyone please help me in resolving this issue?
[image: Terminal without prompt]

Comment: Well, have you looked at what's in your `.bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, etc.?

Comment: Below link has the contents of .bashrc in home directory. There was no .bashrc in /etc.

http://pastebin.com/QxVbBLa8

Do I have to change anything in this file ?

Comment: @muru This [link](http://pastebin.com/0QnArUUE) has the contents of /etc/bash.bashrc. Could you please take a look and let me know if something is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason - there was a backslash at the end of [~/.bashrc](http://pastebin.com/QxVbBLa8) file. This will allow the user to enter arguments for the last command listed in that file. Since the .bashrc file executes when a terminal is opened, I was not able to see the prompt until I pressed Ctrl+C. Thanks for all the responses.